# R: Sum counts of data every hour. Data in non-continuous 5 second intervals

Tags: r, datetime, sum

I have data that is in 5 second intervals but wasn't collected continuously. There is a column that can one of three possibilities, ether `A`, `B` or `C`.

```
datetime                    c1
2000-01-01 00:00:00          A      
2000-01-01 00:00:05          B
2000-01-01 00:00:10          B
2000-01-01 00:00:15          A
2000-01-01 00:06:05          C
2000-01-01 00:06:05          C
2000-01-01 01:00:05          B
```

I am trying to get the count of each `A`, `B` and `C`. each hour. So from `2000-01-01 00:00:00` to `2000-01-01 01:00:00` there were so many A's, B's and C's.

Expected output:

```
starttime                countA   countB   countC
2000-01-01 00:00:00         2        2        2
2000-01-01 01:00:00         n        1        n
2000-01-01 02:00:00         n        n        n
2000-01-01 03:00:00         n        n        n
```

or

```
        hour               c1     count    
 2000-01-01 00:00:00        A        2        
 2000-01-01 00:00:00        B        2
 2000-01-01 00:00:00        C        3
 2000-01-01 01:00:00        B        1
         ...
 2000-01-01 07:00:00        A        n
```

Comment: Not clear though.  Perhaps `df1 %>% group_by(c1, date5sec = cut(datetime, breaks = "5 sec")) %>% tally()` with `dplyr` assuming 'datetime' is `POSIXct`

Comment: How can I clarify it to help?

Comment: From the example you posted, it seems that there is a single count for each unique 'c1'  I would suggest to post an example that gives some changes in frequency along with the expected output (if I am not mistaken)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your first suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be one way to achieve your goal. First of all, given 00:00:00 is included in the first hour, I think you want to include 01:00:00 in the next hour. In this approach, you want to create two variables. One is `date` and the other is `hour`. I created them in `group_by()` using `format()`. I defined groups using these two variables as well as `c1`. Then, I counted how many rows exist for each group with `sammarise()`. Please note that your data frame is called `mydf` here.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
group_by(date = format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d"),
         hour = format(datetime, "%H"),
         c1) %>%
summarize(count = n())

#        date  hour    c1 count
#       <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 2000-01-01    00     A     2
#2 2000-01-01    00     B     2
#3 2000-01-01    00     C     2
#4 2000-01-01    01     B     1
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(946684800, 946684805, 946684810, 
946684815, 946685165, 946685165, 946688405), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), c1 = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"B")), .Names = c("datetime", "c1"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That is a good way of splitting it.  I should have thought about it.  Plus one.

Comment: @akrun The `format()` approach is something I learned from you. Credit goes to you.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Would I be able to aggregate the `date` and `hour` column to allow for plotting over time. Where x axis is time and y is count of each c1?

Comment: @MB_analyst What about something like this? Add the following line after the summarize line: `mutate(x = paste(date[1], as.numeric(hour[1]), "H", collapse = " "))`

Comment: Do I fill `x` in with my `df`? I'm getting: `Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default`

Comment: `mydf %> group_by(date = format(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d"), hour = format(datetime, "%H"), c1) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>% mutate(x = paste(date[1], as.numeric(hour[1]), "H", collapse = " "))` This creates a new column called `x`. Can you see it?